# Parsing in a MediaWiki DPL Regular Expression

Tags: regex, mediawiki

I'm tring to use the `{{PAGENAME}}` magic word in a regular expression to include an article based on the value of a parameter passed to a template. When I use the following statement with the article name hard-coded it correctly selects the articles I want:

```
includematch = /reportType\s*=\s*AccountReport/s
```

However, when I transclude the DPL into the `AccountReport` article, the following doesn't work:

```
includematch = /reportType\s*=\s*{{PAGENAME}}/s
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is `{{PAGENAME}}` being parsed before being used in the regular expression or is it trying to match the literal string?

Answer (score 1):

I was using the DPL tag `<dpl>` but it wasn't parsing `{{PAGENAME}}` before applying the regular expression. When I changed it to use the parser function `{{#dpl:` then `{{PAGENAME}}` was evaluated and used within the regular expression as I required.

Answer (score 1):

The way the dpl code is read makes it impossible for it to read the magic word. Use the dpl extension instead:

```
{{#dpl|code goes here}}
```